# Weird zooming and dimensions behavior with device toolbar and responsive layout in chrome and edge

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, zooming, responsive, dimensions

For an unknown reason my chrome developper tools **device toolbar** has started acting strangely when testing responsive mode.
When toggling it ON, the website is completely zoomed out, the dimensions of the page are not the one displayed in the toolbar, and the layout will not adjust responsively :

[image: device toolbar toggle ON]

When I'm toggling the device toolbar OFF, it works fine, I can resize the window and the layout will adjust responsively.

[image: device toolbar toggle OFF]

Chrome version : Version 96.0.4664.110 (Build officiel) (64 bits)

Note : I picked the google website as an example but it's the same for some page I'm working on locally.

Note 2: Same in Edge

Note 3: device toolbar works perfectly in Mozilla it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Ok wow, it seems like the answer is to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Hey there - I'm experiencing the same issue and the meta line doesn't work for me. Did you find out anymore about this?